# Overflow auto and height not working in Chrome on mobile

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="service-table">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Text</td>
                <td>Text</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have a table with this Bootstrap class. Here is my div CSS:

```
.service-table {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I'm trying to fix the height if the table height is taller than 100px and show the scrollbar. On desktop or mobile in other browsers it is fine (on desktop Chrome it's fine too). But on mobile Chrome the scrollbar does not appear so the height is not 100px.

Comment: I added more rows to your table to make it exceed 100px in height and it works as expected: http://jsbin.com/rarayurina/edit?html,css,output

Comment: i will test on phone thank u :)

Comment: Works on my phone. Test fullscreen here: http://output.jsbin.com/rarayurina/quiet

Comment: i tested on other phone on chrome it works if u add this comment to answer i can check thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added more rows to your table to make it exceed 100px in height and it works as expected: [See my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380680/overflow-auto-and-height-not-working-in-chrome-on-mobile?noredirect=1#comment73824072_43380680).